# Download all nltk packages in google colaboratory at once

Tags: python, package, nltk, google-colaboratory

I want to use stopwords in my code on google colab, there are no errors when I import stuff regarding nltk but when I use stopwords in my code google colab gives this error:-

```
Resource 'corpora/stopwords.zip/stopwords/' not found.  Please
use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:  >>>
nltk.download()
```

But when I do:-

```
 import nltk
 nltk.download()
```

It gives me all the packages list so I have to select 1 to download, in terminal I could do "all" to download all packages but how an I do that in google colab? I don't want to add a name everytime to download stuff. this is what colab shows me when I do "nltk.download()":-

### NLTK Downloader

### d) Download    l) List     u) Update    c) Config    h) Help    q) Quit

```
 Downloader> d

 Download which package (l=list; x=cancel)?
```

Is there any way I can download all packages of nltk at once to my project in google colab?

Comment: Most probably you don't need all packages. Try `Downloader> popular`

Comment: Yeah I dont, but it takes a lot of time to look for each package and then download it, besides "popular" doesn't work.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I reached this page When I faced same problem.
I can use "popular" with this code at google colab.

```
import nltk
nltk.download("popular")
```

Answer (score 7):

Use:

```
import nltk

nltk.download('all')
```

It worked for me.

Comment: How does that add further more than @Bal Krishna Jha answer?

Answer (score 5):

You have several other options:

```
all-corpora......... All the corpora
all-nltk............ All packages available on nltk_data gh-pages
                           branch
all................. All packages
book................ Everything used in the NLTK Book
popular............. Popular packages
tests............... Packages for running tests
```

You can use them as :

```
import nltk
nltk.download('book')
#or
nltk.download('tests')
#or
nltk.download('all-corpora')# not recommended as it download huge amount of data.
```

Answer (score 0):

import nltk

nltk.download('all')

Worked for me!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).